How to display sparkline charts inside data frame cell values using reactable?
I have a data frame df that looks like



Index
Value1
Range




0.1
0.2
c(1,2,3)


0.1
0.2
c(8,2,6)



I want to display the table using R Shiny such that the Range column is a sparkline line chart where each cell is created using the list in Range
For that I am using the following method
sparkline_html <- function (value) {
    sparkline(value, type = "line")
}

df$Price_Range2 = NA

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    df$Price_Range2[i] = sparkline_html(df$Price_Range[[i]])
}

reactable(data_latest_ordered)

The cells in Price_Range2 column should look like the figure below

But what I see as the output is

Instead of displaying the charts it displays [object Object ]
Please tell me what should I do to make the correction.

{gt} and {gtExtras} can help with this:
library(shiny)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(dplyr)

gt_tbl <- dplyr::tibble(
  price_range  = list(
    c(0.964, 0.685, 0.593), 
    c(0.561, 0.600, 0.868), 
    c(0.964, 0.742, 0.950)
  )
) |>
  dplyr::mutate(price_range_2 = price_range) |>
  gt::gt() |>
  gtExtras::gt_plt_sparkline(column = 2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  gt::gt_output(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- gt::render_gt(expr = gt_tbl)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Created on 2024-04-08 with reprex v2.1.0

There is an example of using sparklines in the reactable docs.
https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#custom-rendering
library(reactable)
library(dplyr)
library(sparkline)

data <- chickwts %>%
  group_by(feed) %>%
  summarise(weight = list(weight)) %>%
  mutate(boxplot = NA, sparkline = NA)

reactable(data, columns = list(
  weight = colDef(cell = function(values) {
    sparkline(values, type = "bar", chartRangeMin = 0, chartRangeMax = max(chickwts$weight))
  }),
  boxplot = colDef(cell = function(value, index) {
    sparkline(data$weight[[index]], type = "box")
  }),
  sparkline = colDef(cell = function(value, index) {
    sparkline(data$weight[[index]])
  })
))


